# retain popup window when navigating website

Tags: javascript

The following code produces a javascript popup when a page is loaded and then closes the popup window when the parent window is closed.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  var player;
  function load() {
   player = window.open('http://www.google.com','player','height=320,width=320,scrollbars,resizable'); 
  }
  function unload() {
      player.close();
  }
window.onload = load;
window.onunload = unload;
</script>
```

This is working fine, however it closes the popup window when switching pages on the site. Is there any way this can be altered to keep the popup window until the actual URL/Site window is closed?

Comment: You're probably going to run into popup blocker problems with that method of opening the popup.

Comment: I'm unsure how your comment relates to my question...

Comment: It doesn't; it's just a comment :-)  I started typing in an answer but it got long and I was called away; sorry. James Johnson's answer is basically what I would have suggested - poll the parent (window.opener) from the client.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check the status of the parent window from the child, instead of vice-versa.

This code has not been tested, but I'm taking a stab at the concept:

```
window.opener.onunload = 
     setTimeout(
          function(){ 
              if (!window.opener) self.close(); 
          }, 1000);
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you would put this code in the child (popup) window.

Comment: Hey, I've tested this code but im not sure if i implemented it correctly because the window closes whenever i navigate to a new page within the same website the parent window was created. I used this code: <script>
window.opener.onunload = 
     setTimeout(
          function(){ 
              if (!window.opener) self.close(); 
          }, 1000);

</script>

Comment: Just to clarify, I added the code as it looks above. If I've closed the website it doesnt close the popup. but if I go to the popup and reload it after the website is closed it closes the popup. how do i make it constantly check tosee if the parent was closed? Do I have to change the unload function in the original code?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is NO, the only way to hook into the event that closes the window is `onunload`, which fires when the document is unloaded (like when you navigate to another page).

Maybe you could check `window.opener` on the popup (with a timer, or onfocus), to check if the window that originated the popup still exists, then close the popup if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
<script language="Javascript">
    var player;
    function load() {
        player = window.open('http://www.google.com','player','height=320,width=320,scrollbars,resizable');
    }
    function unload() {
        if (!(window.location.equals('http://yourSiteName.com'))) {
            player.close();
        }
    }
window.onload = load();
window.onunload = unload();
</script>
```